# add values in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add values in a dataframe. But i want to write clean code (short and faster). I really want to improve my skill in writing.
Suppose that we have a DataFrame and 3 values

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"Name":[],"ID":[],"LastName":[]})
value1="ema"
value2=023123
value3="Perez"
```

I can write:

```
df.append([value1,value2,value3])
```

but the output is gonna create a new column
like

```
0  | Name | ID | LastName

ema | nan | nan | nan

023123 | nan | nan| nan

Perez | nan | nan | nan
```

i want the next output with the best clean code

```
Name | ID | LastName

ema | 023123 | Perez
```

There are a way to do this , without append one by one? (i want the best short\fast code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the values to `dict` then use `append`

```py
df.append(dict(zip(['Name', 'ID', 'LastName'],[value1,value2,value3])), ignore_index=True)
```

```
    Name    ID  LastName
0   ema 23123.0 Perez
```

Answer (score 1):

Here the explanation:

First set your 3 values into an array

```
values=[value1,value2,value3]
```

and make variable as index marker when lopping latter

```
i = 0
```

Then use the code below

```
for column in df.columns:
    df.loc[0,column] = values[i]
    i+=1
```

`column in df.columns` will give you all the name of the column in the DataFrame

and `df.loc[0,column] = values[i]` will set the values at index i to row=0 and column=column

[Here the code and the result]

[image: 1]

Comment: looping + pandas dataframes is not *The Best Clean Code*

Comment: But it very readable, but okay i will edit my statement hehe, thankyou